FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory error happens randomly when writing logs in Databricks
I've created a logger that writes a log file to a folder in a Databricks project:
def configure_logger(logger, logfile, level=logging.DEBUG):
    """
    Configures a logger with both file and stream handlers.
    
    Parameters:
    - logger (logging.Logger): The logger to configure.
    - logfile (str): The path to the logfile.
    - level (int, optional): The logging level. Defaults to logging.DEBUG.
    
    Returns:
    - tuple: A tuple containing the configured logger and the file handler.
    """
    logger.setLevel(level)

    # Create a file handler with detailed formatting for log output
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile, mode="w")
    fformatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(fformatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    # Create a stream handler with simple formatting for cell output
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    sformatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    stream_handler.setFormatter(sformatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    # Remove random Pyspark logs
    logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logging.getLogger("Comm").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    return logger, file_handler


# Set up root logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logfile = '/Workspace/Project/Logs/dev/dev_20SEP2024.log'  # example

# Ensure the directory exists
log_dir = os.path.dirname(logfile)
if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
    os.makedirs(log_dir)

logger, file_handler = configure_logger(logger, logfile=logfile)

The code works majority of the time, but every once in a while I'll get the following error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Workspace/Project/Logs/dev/dev_20SEP2024.log'
File <command-3660103723975015>, line 10
      7 if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
      8     os.makedirs(log_dir)
---> 10 logger, file_handler = configure_logger(logger, logfile=logfile)

But the folder exits.
%sh
ls '/Workspace/Project/Logs/dev'
# returns dev_16SEP2024.log

Even though the folder does exist, and has previous days logs in it. After restarting the notebook and waiting a bit, it seems to work again or randomly restarting it. Not sure what the issue can be but seems like something in Databricks or the logging library. Has anyone dealt with this? Whatever it is, I need to figure out why it does this since others might encounter this issue.

It seems like the file handler was getting stuck or something if I reran the code without closing the handler. I think the issue is resolved now after adding this:
def configure_logger(logger, logfile=None, level=logging.DEBUG):
    logger.setLevel(level)

    try:
        # Create a file handler with detailed formatting for log output
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile, mode="w")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # For some reason, sometimes this error is triggered even though the file
        # exists. Removing the file fixes this.
        os.remove(logfile) 
        # Create a file handler with detailed formatting for log output
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile, mode="w")
    
    fformatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(fformatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    # Create a stream handler with simple formatting for cell output
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    sformatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    stream_handler.setFormatter(sformatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    # Remove random Pyspark logs
    logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logging.getLogger("Comm").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    return logger, file_handler

